# Why don't virtual electrons get generated near protons to form atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, entropy, virtual-particles

If forming an atom is a more stable state for both the electron and the proton, why don't virtual electrons get generated near protons so that they combine with them to form atoms, and then release the energy (due to the newly acquired stability) into the vacuum again?
I would guess it's because that released energy is not enough to make up for that of the electron, but I haven't been able to find the amount of energy released on internet.

Comment: Are you searching for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization ?

Comment: This process is allowed in theory, but requires binding energies beyond the mass energy of an electron-positron pair (around 1 MeV) – otherwise the process would violate energy conservation in the asymptotic limit. This requires nuclei with higher $Z$ than have ever been synthesized.

Comment: Are you imagining a free proton spontaneously turning into a neutral hydrogen atom plus a positron? I have a vague recollection that this process may be allowed near a nucleus with charge $Z \approx 137 \approx 1/\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the "fine structure constant" describing the strength of the electromagnetic interaction.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Do you know where I could find the information you are referring to?

Comment: You might be interested in Schwinger Pair-Production: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect
See also Chapter 33.4.3 in "QFT and the SM" by M.D.Schwartz

Comment: When a free electron binds to a free proton to make the Hydrogen ground state atom, the energy you get from this binding is about 13.6eV. For the creation of the electron-positron pair, you will be needing to supply an energy of 1.022MeV; the binding energy is a negligible correction, it is energetically forbidden to happen, unless you are considering some other extreme scenario around this.